# Sql leftJoin query using laravel syntax showing error

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

This is my query that i used for left join, it is working fine but something is missing when I convert it to laravel syntax.

Query to convert is

```
$result = DB::select("select amenities.name as 
name,amenities.type_id,amenities.id as id, amenities.icon, rooms.id as status 
from amenities left join rooms on find_in_set(amenities.id, rooms.amenities) 
and rooms.id = $room_id and type_id !=4");
```

and the I am doing this

```
$result = DB::table('amenities')
            ->select('amenities.name as name', 'amenities.type_id' , 'amenities.id as id'
                , 'amenities.icon', 'rooms.id as status' )
            ->leftJoin('rooms', function ($join) {
                 $join->on('FIND_IN_SET(amenities.id, rooms.amenities)')
                      ->where('rooms.id' , '=', '$room_id')
                      ->where('type_id','!=', 4);
            })->get();
```

The error is

> InvalidArgumentException in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\arheb\Arheb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause.php
>   line 79: Not enough arguments for the on clause.

Comment: There is no `Where` clause in the original query. Can you change the `where` to `and` in the second query you are trying.

Comment: How do I add and instead of where, so you mean that i add and inside on bracket, I dont know how laravel works with and, that is why i used where so it treat it like and.

Comment: Sorry. Change the `where` words to `on`. That should infer the `and` conditions on the `join`.

Comment: Do you mean like this one                                                                                                  $result = DB::table('amenities')
           ->select('amenities.name as name', 'amenities.type_id' , 'amenities.id as id'
               , 'amenities.icon', 'rooms.id as status' )
           ->leftJoin('rooms', function ($join) {
                $join->on(DB::raw("find_in_set(amenities.id, rooms.amenities)"))
                     ->on('rooms.id' , '=', '$room_id')
                     ->on('type_id','!=', 4);
           })->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong. I assume that `amenities.id` and `rooms.amenities` are attributes of `amenities` and `rooms` table respectively.

> MySQL FIND_IN_SET() returns the position of a string if it is present (as a substring) within a list of strings.

You need to pass column names in first and second parameter of `on()` function.

```
$result = DB::table('amenities')
            ->select('amenities.name as name', 'amenities.type_id' , 'amenities.id as id'
                , 'amenities.icon', 'rooms.id as status' )
            ->leftJoin('rooms', function ($join) {
                 $join->on('amenities.id', '=', 'rooms.amenities')
                      ->where('rooms.id' , '=', '$room_id')
                      ->where('type_id','!=', 4);
            })->get();
```

Comment: Still showing me error Not enough arguments for the on clause.

Comment: which code? I copied your code and check it but it is showing error

Comment: so why can't we use find_in_set, is it not supported by laravel

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
$result = DB::table('amenities')
           ->select('amenities.name as name', 'amenities.type_id' , 'amenities.id as id'
               , 'amenities.icon', 'rooms.id as status' )
           ->leftJoin('rooms', function ($join) {
                $join->on(DB::raw("find_in_set(amenities.id, rooms.amenities)"))
                     ->where('rooms.id' , '=', '$room_id')
                     ->where('type_id','!=', 4);
           })->get();
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: No dear it is showing the same error  InvalidArgumentException in F:\xampp\htdocs\arheb\Arheb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause.php line 79:
Not enough arguments for the on clause.